# Autoscaling on queuemessages

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus, autoscaling

I am testing autoscaling features on azure with service bus queue messages and worker role.

Simple scenario in autoscale is , for more than 10 messages in the queue per instance, autoscale happens. however, during testing, noticed that even though I had pushed more than 200 messages in the queue, even after half n hour,

1)Only one instance was scaled up(started with 1 , it became 2)
2)None of the two instance were stable i.e in "Running" state.

This has me confused, are following possible reasons for inconsistent showing?

1)My subscription is company msdn subscription with capped limit per month (which is of course only meant for dev work).
2)I had pushed 200 messages within space of few seconds.. obviously this can be a production scenario..but does it hamper..

What could be possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure's auto-scaling works on 60min aggregate periods.  Once it does kick in, it usually adds 1 instance at a time and it takes 10-12minutes to add an instance to a cloud service (which is what I'm assuming you have).

If you want a ton more control and options when it comes to auto-scaling, consider 3rd party products that specialize in this, like [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) which is a successor of AzureWatch - both of which I'm associated with

Special note as to why your instances were both non-Ready during the scaling period:
It is because you started with 1 instance and went to 2.  If you were to start with 2 instances and go to 3+, your first two instances would be fine.  This is a special issue with Azure's load balancer and I forget the explanation that Microsoft gave regarding it, but it's here somewhere on the forums if you look

Comment: if you can let me know the explaination behind that, it would be great. Is it the SLA issue? as SLA is not in picture if you don't have 2 or more instances?

Comment: It's not specifically an SLA issue (although I'm sure SLA relies on this fact too), but I think it's because their load balancer goes thru a thru a different pattern and needs to yank out your first instance out of itself in order to rebuild the load-balanced set with 2+ instances

Comment: i understand the fact that new instance is up depending on the average usage over an hour..but how about queue based .. for example after optimizing my queue reading , it's pretty fast now.. but still. when I have set criteria for each instance as 10 messages.. and when there are more than 100 pending in the queue.. it still doesnt start to spin up new instance.. after some time it does..any thing behind that?

Answer (score 1):

Service bus will eat 200 messages in a few seconds.  Try sending more like 20,000.

Here is a sample, it uses F#, but same concept.
http://indiedevspot.com/2015/03/14/mocking-iot-telemetry-data-with-azure/